# Applications of $FP_\infty$ groups preserving direct systems

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, limits-and-colimits, applications

In [1], the author proves that given a group $G$ and a directed system $(M_\lambda)_\lambda$  of $G$-modules, the induced maps $$\varinjlim H^k(G,M_\lambda) \to H^k(G,\varinjlim M_\lambda)$$ are isomorphisms for all $k$ if and only if $G$ is of type $FP_\infty$.

This seems like a useful result whenever one considers directed systems of $G$-modules, but I haven't been able to find any concrete examples.

My questions are basically:

- Are there any applications or examples where one wants to compute group cohomology with respect to a direct system of coefficients?
- Are there any concrete application of Brown's theorem above, i.e. given some fixed group $G$ of type $FP_\infty$, one wants to compute $H^k(G,\varinjlim M_\lambda)$ and uses this "commutativity"?

[1] *Brown, Kenneth S.*, [**Homological criteria for finiteness**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02565740), Comment. Math. Helv. 50, 129-135 (1975). [ZBL0302.18010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.18010).

Comment: My accepted answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272715/cohomological-dimension-of-g-times-g/272755#272755 uses this property  of $FP_{\infty}$ groups.  The main applications I use tend to be of the flavor that you can reduce things to finitely generated modules because every module is a direct limit of finitely generated modules, but I don't do group cohomology for a living.