# Groups with unusual cohomological dimension of direct product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\cd{cd}$Are there any known examples of non-free groups with a property that $\cd(G)+1 = \cd(G \times G)$, or, less restrictive, $G, H$ with $\cd \neq 1, \infty$ such that $\cd(H)+1 = \cd(G \times H)$?

Comment: This question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272715/cohomological-dimension-of-g-times-g is relevant

Comment: Although question is relevant, (currently absent) answer to it would not provide an answer to my  question as far as I can see and vise versa.

Comment: That questions shows that the "typical" behavior is $cd(G\times G) =2cd(G)$ for $FP_{\infty}$-groups for example and also if you ask $cd(G)=cd(G\times G)$ then $G$ has infinite cohomological dimension.  I didn't claim it answers your question. It's for context.

Comment: For the less restrictive you want neither one free right?

Comment: ...I think I need both have cd greater than than one for my possible application (namely, some clarifications/upgrades in Kan-Thurston construction; such groups can provide a source for suspension-like functor on crossed modules with extra structure, in order to get full functor from hoTop to a certain localisation of category of that contraptions), but I guess any example can be pretty illuminating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G=(\mathbb{Q},+)$.  Then ${\rm cd}(G)=2$ and ${\rm cd}(G\times G)=3$.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: $K(Q,1)$ can be built as the mapping telescope, or homotopy colimit, of the sequence of self maps of $S^1$ of degrees 2,3,4,5... Geometrically this can be realized by gluing together a sequence of cylinders $S^1 \times [0,1]$ by the appropriate maps at the ends. Hence $cd(Q) \leq 2$, and it is not 1 by Swan. $K(Q \oplus Q, 1)$ can be built similarly from cylinders on 2-tori, hence $cd \leq 3$. To see that $cd(Q\oplus Q)$ is not 2, note that the uncountable group $Ext^1_Z(H_2(K(Q \oplus Q,1),Z),Z) = Ext^1_Z(Q\oplus Q, Z)$ injects into $H^3(K(Q\oplus Q,1), Z)$ by universal coefficients.

Comment: According to Kropholler's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320997/cohomological-dimension-of-direct-product this works more generally for any solvable group of cohomological dimension 2